# A question about comma usage: should it be "me," or "me", in this case?

Tags: punctuation, commas, style

I am reading an article here:

https://waitbutwhy.com/2014/12/what-makes-you-you.html

> When you say the word “me,” you probably feel pretty clear about what that means. It’s one of the things you’re clearest on in the whole world

I noticed a very detailed point: the `,` in the sentence is inside the `"`. Is that a typo of the original post or it's a legal usage?

Comment: This is a matter of style. In the US, most writers prefer to put a comma or a period inside the quotation marks. But in the UK, it goes outside.

Comment: @Robusto That question was about an entire clause in quotes, while this question only has quotes around an individual word. So I would put the comma outside, as it is attached to the entire clause, not the quoted word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's all about the styles of American and British English.

In NAmE:

> When you say the word 'me,' you probably....

In BrE:

> When you say the word 'me', you probably...

Not just this, here I give you a very good reference that talks about more than what you are looking for. [Here it is.](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/08/punctuating-around-quotation-marks.html)